# How to create PIP (Policy Information Point) in WSO2IS 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, pip, xacml

A lot of good forums explain how to create the PIP in WSO2IS v 3.2.3 http://xacmlinfo.com/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/ and http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/04/xacml-policy-information-point.html
I tried the first link and everything works for me. 
However version WSO2 4.1.0 which supports XACML 3.0 (for which I use it) does not allow the same way of PIP creation , it does not have entitlement-config.xml, how to create PIP in WSo2IS version 4.1.0 , maybe anyone knows ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There are some config file and API changes with Identity server 4.x.x version. It seems to be that blog post has been updated by mentioning it [1]. Please check it again.  However you can find the sample from here [2]

[1] http://xacmlinfo.com/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/
[2] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.entitlement.pip/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/security/entitlement.properties to add your attribute finder and the properties required.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [1] would be helpful if you are using 4.x.x

[1] http://blog.ashansa.org/2013/09/write-simple-jdbc-pip-attribute-finder.html